# Mail delivery hindered by alias?

Tags: centos6, sendmail

Account info exists for receiving email.

However, all mail sent to info is delivered to root.

It looks to me this is because the following aliases exist (as shown by praliases):

```
info: postmaster
postmaster: root
```

It makes no difference what I put in the sendmail aliases file (and create the aliases.db + restart sendmail). Things stay as mentioned above.

Is there any way I can remove the alias for: info, so that (hopefully) info will receive email?
The shell built-ins: alias and unalias appear to have no effect on the sendmail aliases.

Comment: 1) Have you tried to remove alias for info and execute `newaliases` command after it? 2) emails to root should be redirected to non privileged account

Comment: 1) Yes I have. Even an **empty** aliases file does not solve this problem 2) some of them need to go to root 3) even with an empty aliases file, the list produced by praliases is quite long

Comment: **Problem solved** It appears the contents of /etc/aliases is used by newaliases. Removing the unwanted alias resulted in the info account receiving email (as wanted/needed).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP apparently solved it according to comments.

Answer (score 1):

Off hand Sendmail uses three different maps which can potentially be the cause of that:

- The access map `/etc/mail/access`
- The virtual user map `/etc/mail/virtualuserdb`
- The local user alias db, `/etc/aliases`

which I think are consulted in that same order of precedence.

P.S. I m on mobile and can't verify the exact file names.